# Spring boot failes with 'void org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>(java.lang.Object[])': java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: spring

I have a spring boot app that I am trying to boot as a Lambda with the [aws-serverless-java-container-spring library](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/wiki/Quick-start---Spring-Boot), and upon startup I get the error:

```
Error loading class works.weave.socks.cart.StreamLambdaHandler: 'void org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>(java.lang.Object[])': java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>(java.lang.Object[])'
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:120)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:84)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:62)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:342)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140)
    at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.initialize(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:195)
    at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.InitializationWrapper.start(InitializationWrapper.java:35)
    at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder.buildAndInitialize(SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder.java:81)
    at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:93)
    at works.weave.socks.cart.StreamLambdaHandler.<clinit>(StreamLambdaHandler.java:18)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
```

How can I resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common answer to this question is that you have mixed up some libraries, although I could never find good instructions on how to resolve the issue.

The key thing to understand here is that the `org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener` class comes from the `spring-cloud-context` library, while `org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder` comes from the `spring-boot` library.

Using `mvn dependency:tree` I could see the following output:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:1.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:1.1.6.RELEASE:compile
```

This told me that the `spring-cloud-starter-zipkin` dependency was contributing the `spring-cloud-context` library. Updating the `spring-cloud-starter-zipkin` dependency gave me this result:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
```

This resolved the error.